# preg_replace - url e quebra de linha

Tags: php

Eu tenho esta função abaixo:

```
function filterEmail($text)
{
    return preg_replace('/(.*)[a-z0-9\.\_\-]+@[a-z0-9\.\_\-]+\.[a-z]+(.*)/i','', $text);
}
```

Ela remove linhas quem possuem e-mail.

Eu tenho uma `textarea`, e as vezes os usuário colocam o e-mail, então sempre que ele colocar o e-mail, essa função remove.

Ex:
Olá pessoal, tudo bem?

Gostei muito do site.

Me envie um e-mail teste@teste.com.br

Com essa função, o conteúdo fica assim:

Ex:
Olá pessoal, tudo bem?
Gostei muito do site.

---

Até ai tudo certo. O que eu preciso é a mesma função, mas que também remova URL. Se possível utilizando o `preg_replace`.

E por fim, as vezes os usuários colocam três quebras de linhas `(\n\n)` - Preciso que sempre que colocarem três quebras de linhas (ou mais), ele deixe apenas duas. Mas apenas quando forem três quebras de linhas ou mais..

Ex:

Olá pessoal, tudo bem?

Gostei muito do site.

---

Deve ficar:

Olá pessoal, tudo bem?

Gostei muito do site.

Comment: Alguem?????????

Comment: Uma dica, ao invés de utilizar a eliminação da linha inteira com o preg_replace, poderia deletar apenas o e-mail, pois o usuario pode digitar outras coisas na linha junto com o email

eu utilizo :
`preg_replace('/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)/','', $text);`

Answer (score 1):

Tenta o seguinte:

```
<?php
function filterEmail($texto) {

$texto = preg_replace('/\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]/i', '', $texto);
$texto = preg_replace('/(.*)[a-z0-9\.\_\-]+@[a-z0-9\.\_\-]+\.[a-z]+(.*)/i','', $texto);
$texto = preg_replace('/[\n\r]{3,}/',"\n\n",$texto);
return $texto;

}

$string = "Olá pessoal, tudo bem?

Gostei muito do site.

Me envie um e-mail teste@teste.com.br
http://www.codigosnaweb.com";
echo filterEmail($string);
?>
```